# why is this "He is offside!"(spoj) solution giving my WA?

Tags: c++

ideone link: https://ideone.com/hOBBMA
problem link: http://www.spoj.com/problems/OFFSIDE/
code:

```
enter code here
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
int n1,n2,i,j;
while(1)
{
    int count=0;
    cin>>n1>>n2;
    if(n1==0 && n2==0)
        break;
    else
    {
        int a[n1],d[n2];
        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        for(i=0;i<n2;i++)
        {
            cin>>d[i];
        }

        for(i=0;i<n1;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<n2;j++)
            {
                if(a[i]>d[j])
                {
                count++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if(count>=2)
        cout<<"N"<<endl;
    else
        cout<<"Y"<<endl;
}
return 0;
```

}
it gives the correct answer with the given test cases but apparently it's a WA

Comment: and the question is...?

Comment: "why is this “He is offside!”(spoj problem) solution giving my WA?"

Comment: what are the input? n1? n2? WA?

Comment: the problem link is over the code....

Comment: And "WA" is... Western Australia?

Comment: The program gives the correct result. What is the problem? What did you expect? The input shall give N Y N.

Comment: wa:wrong answer :D
@nielsen
that's the problem,it gives correct answer according to the test cases but when i submit it it gives wrong answer

Comment: which answer do you think is wrong? case 1, case 2 or case 3?

Comment: in the gives test cases all of them are correct so my algorithms is correct according if you only consider the given test cases but apparently the algorithm is not generally correct and i don't have the test cases that make the algorithm fall

Comment: well - difficult to help you when you don't have a failing case. Also I lack a description of the program. What is the input? Number of persons close to the goal and their distance? The program looks fine to me! Why do you think it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this input; two attackers at 400m from the goal and two defenders also at 400m from the goal. Your code would count '0' i.e. offside whilst according to the rules neither of the attackers isn't.

> An attacking player is offside if he is nearer to his opponents’ goal
> line than the second last opponent. [**This is not true for any of the attackers in this case so definitely not an offside**]
>
> A player is not offside if he is level with the second last opponent [**In this case they *are* level so certainly not offside**] or he is level with the last two opponents [**And this is true too**].

```
2 2
400 400
400 400
0 0
```